# set value in pandas not knowing if column and row exists, avoiding NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a shallow array in pandas containing pair of values (concept - document)

```
           doc1 doc2
concept1   1     0
concept2   0     1
concept3   1     0
```

I parse a XML file and get pairs (concepts - doc)
every time a new pair comes in I add it to the pandas.

Since the pairs coming in might or might not contain values already present in the rows and/or columns (whatever new concept or whatever new column) I use the following code:

```
onp=np.arange(1,21,1).reshape(4,5)
oindex=['concept1','concept2','concept3','concept4',]
ohead=['doc1','doc2','doc3','doc5','doc6']
data=onp
mydf=pd.DataFrame(data,index=oindex, columns=ohead)
#... loop ...
mydf.loc['conceptXX','ep8']=1
```

it works well, only that the value in the data frame is 1.0 and not 1, boolean, and when a new row and/or column is added then the rest of the values are NaN. How can I avoid that. All the values added should be 0 or 1. (Note: the intention is to have also some columns for calculations, so I can not transform just all the dataframe into boolean type for instance:

```
mydf=mydf.astype(object)
```

thanks.

SECOND EDIT AFTER ALollz COMMENT
More explanation of the real problem. 
I have an XML file that gives me the data in the following way:

```
<names>
    <name>michael</name>
        <documents>
            <document>doc1</document>
            <document>doc2</document>
        </documents>
    </name>
    <name>mathieu</name>
        <documents>
            <document>doc1</document>
            <document>docN</document>
        </documents>
    </name>
</names>
...
```

I want to pass this data to a dataframe to make calculations. Basically there are names that appear in different documents when parsing the XML with:

```
tree = ET.parse(myinputFile)
root = tree.getroot()
```

I am going adding one by one new values into the dataframe.
When adding sometimes a name is already present in the dataframe, but a new doc has to be added and viceversa.
I hope to have clarify a bit

I was about to write this as solution:

```
mydf.fillna(0, inplace=True)
mydf=mydf.astype(int)
```

changing all the NaN values by 0 and then convert them into int to avoid floats.
that has a negative side because i might want to have some columns with text data. in that case an error occur.

Comment: You can't really. `DataFrames` are rectangular, so adding a single value at one index to a new column forces it to assign `NaN` to all other indices in that column. Since a column must have a single `dtype` and there is no `NaN` integer or bool support in pandas the column is coerced to `float`. You can perhaps typcast the columns after your loop, or try to fill the column with a list in one command, which will allow it to remain `int`.

Comment: ok, got it. so there is no other way around as to look if the column exist, if not fill it with zeros, look if the row exist if not fill it with zeros, and then use .loc to set the 1 value. Still I smell that this pandas guys thought about this problem.

Comment: Typically you don't add single elements to a `DataFrame` one at a time. If you give an example of your real problem, (how to get an existence table from a column of tuples for instance) there are likely efficient ways to solve that, including filling the missing values with (0) and typecasting to int, instead of trying to solve this other problem that isn't the main issue.